# How do I restore a mysql dump that was created in xml format?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I have a rather big XML formatted MySQL dump

It was created with the `--xml` param (`-X`) param of mysqldump.

I need to import it in.

[This article](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/restoring-xml-formatted-mysql-dumps.html) from 2010 indicates that there was no "built in" way of importing this in. However many years have passed and stuff changes.

Is there a clean/simple way of importing this dump in, or do I need to run through a conversion first?

If I need to convert, anyone got tools for it that are still maintained?

Comment: You might find this of [interest](http://rpbouman.blogspot.ie/2010/04/restoring-xml-formatted-mysql-dumps.html).

Comment: linked in my question :) also does not work for my dump (too big, xslt transformer crashes)

Comment: Got trapped by the difference between .au and .ie on the blogspot thing. Didn't think to double check that :-( - ah well, back to the drawing board! :-)

Comment: yeah I am actually writing a parser at the moment :(

Comment: I see this question is almost 4 years old. Were you able to get this working?

Comment: Any Progress here ?! The Tool from Roland seems not to work for Big Files ( `https://github.com/rpbouman/mysqldump-x-restore` ).